# CSS padding automatic linebreak

Tags: css, padding, line-breaks

I've following html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>
        a very long long long, really very very long headline ...
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

and following css:

```
.container{
  width:200px;
}

.header h1{
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  display: inline;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

The problem is, that the browser adds a linebreak because of the long header and small width of the wrapping container. Thats fine. But the padding-left will not be added to the broken second and further lines. I can do this with an negative text-indent and positive padding-left to .header. but the background-color will not be moved to left so it seems as would be there still a zero padding.

How can I change this? Any trick available?

Great greetings, Falk

Comment: Just curious, why use `h1` tag and override it as `display: inline`?

Comment: The `h1` tag serves to identify the content as a header.  However, a header can be styled as an inline box depending on the design requirements of the user/client.

Comment: just remove `display:inline`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try changing `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;`.

As I understand it, left and right padding on inline elements will be applied to the beginning and end of the element, regardless of whether there's any line break in between. On a block (or inline-block) element, the padding is applied to the left and right of the entire element.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display for a lot more information!

Comment: But then I will get a full block. But I would like to have different length of the lines.Same length as the text has. So I have to split the header by hand? But then I will have maybe three times an h1. Makes no sense, or I would have to add one h1 and the rest just add an own class. Complicated.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. As it turns out, there's no easy way to do this. See http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/ - I like "Matthew Pennell's Triple Element Method", although if you're happy not supporting IE then "Adam Campbell's box-decoration-break Method" is nicer.

Comment: Thanks Olly! That comment above was helpful!

Answer (score 10):

Along with your existing display-inline:

```
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
box-decoration-break: clone;
```

Note that it is [currently not supported by IE/Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak) and [considered experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) - but it works on other browsers. Might be an option!

This is a fairly new CSS3 tag that might not have been available at the time of the other answers.